# Comparar duas listas em python e retornar correspondências

Tags: python, lista

Como comparar (a moda antiga) duas listas em python e retornar as correspondências dessas duas listas

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-pt, por favor leia o [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/13561), principalmente a seção [achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/13561)

Comment: O que seria "na moda antiga"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A forma mais simples é utilizando um *list comprehension*.

```py
uma_lista = [1, 2, 3, 4,]
outra_lista = [3, 4, 5, 6,]

iguais = [elemento for elemento in uma_lista if elemento in outra_lista]
```

Este comando criará uma nova lista iterando os elementos de `uma_lista` mas apenas adicionando aqueles que estão dentro de `outra_lista`.

E o resultado será a lista `iguais` apenas com os elementos iguais.

```
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 10):

Converta a listas em [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-set) e faça a [intercessão `&`:](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

```
uma_lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
outra_lista = [3, 4, 5, 6]


print(set(uma_lista) & set(outra_lista))
```

resultando:

```
{3, 4}
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/DuasListas)</sup>

Comment: Ótima resposta! Não só porque é mais simples de ver (e entender) o que está acontecendo, mas porque também tenho a impressão de que _sets_ tendem a ser mais performáticos com grandes quantidades de itens. Porém não fiz o teste para confirmar essa hipótese.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Com listas grandes a diferença é brutal: https://ideone.com/xnywb5 - com listas pequenas, nem tanto (e não usar `set` é até um pouco mais rápido): https://ideone.com/CLrWSe

Comment: Obrigado pelos testes, @hkotsubo! Realmente, faz sentido demorar um pouco mais para listas menores por causa do custo de se criar o _set_, correto? Mas nesse tipo de caso (menor), como a diferença é tão irrisória, eu tenderia a preferir perder essa pouquíssima performance em favor da maior legibilidade, que também é um fator importante. :-)

Comment: Eu sabia que havia diferença de performance, mas não eu tinha ideia que era tanta diferença.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Sim, tem o custo de criar os `set`'s, mas que na minha opinião se paga (não só no tempo, mas na questão de semântica/legibilidade que vc mencionou). Lembrando que um `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos, então se a ordem for importante, aí tem que usar as listas mesmo...

Comment: Se precisar de um `set` ordenado tem [aqui](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/0.8.4/) junto de outras coleções ordenadas.

Answer (score 2):

> Outro exemplo com strings poderia ser feito dessa forma:

Se gostaria de subtrair os elementos iguais:

```
uma_lista = ['oi', 'bem', 'certo']
outra_lista = ['oi', 'belo', 'jeito']
iguais = [elemento for elemento in uma_lista if elemento in outra_lista]
print(iguais)

Resultado ['oi']
```

Se gostaria de retornar somente a interseção de todas as letras contidas nas listas:

```
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
uma_lista = ['oi', 'bem', 'certo']
outra_lista = ['oi', 'belo', 'jeito']
for pos, palavras in enumerate(uma_lista):
    lista1 += palavras
for pos, palavras in enumerate(outra_lista):
    lista2 += palavras
lista1 = set(lista1)
lista2 = set(lista2)
print(lista1-lista2)

Resultado: {'b', 't', 'e', 'i', 'o'}
```